# Only Darwin systems greater than 8 (Mac OS X 10.5+) are supported

Tags: ruby, macos

Trying to `gem install rb-fsevent -v '0.4.3.1'` and getting the above error. I'm Mountain Lion (10.8) so I'm not entirely sure what the complaining is about.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: I ended up just updating the gem, but the answer provided also provides valid alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have something to do with dependency on guard...  as far as I can tell, it's only an issue in an old dev branch:

https://github.com/guard/guard/pull/184

I would say either try editing `$RVM_PATH/gems/ruby-x.x.x/guard-1.0.0/lib/vendor/darwin/ext/extconf.rb`, if it exists, along the lines of:

```
sdk_version    = { 9 => '10.5', 10 => '10.6', 11 => '10.7', 12 => '10.8' }[darwin_version]
raise "Only Darwin systems greater than 8 (Mac OS X 10.5+) are supported" unless sdk_version
```

or try installing a newer version of guard/guard-rspec.

Comment: yes I was going to submit a pull request for that but it turns out that updating the gem (rb-fsevent) wasn't a problem so I went with that.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this error by exchange '0.4.3.1' to '>= 0.4.3.1', I think the problem is this version is not the newest and it doesn't support my current Mac OS version.